# How to use Javacpp presets binaries

Tags: java, wrapper, embedded-linux, javacpp, realsense

I'm trying to use the javacpp-presets binaries to access the librealsense library from Java. How do I use them? On the github page it says that it is sufficient to put all the desired JAR files (opencv*.jar, ffmpeg*.jar, etc.), in addition to javacpp.jar, somewhere in my class path.

I've run the following command with these results:

```
$ javac -cp javacpp-presets-bin/javacpp.jar:javacpp-presets-bin/librealsense.jar TestConnection.java
$ java -jar javacpp-presets-bin/javacpp.jar TestConnection
Warning: Could not load platform properties for class TestConnection
$ java -cp javacpp-presets-bin/javacpp.jar:javacpp-presets-bin/librealsense.jar:. TestConnection
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniRealSense in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:804)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:613)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.RealSense.<clinit>(RealSense.java:10)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.RealSense$context.<clinit>(RealSense.java:1566)
    at TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no realsense in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:804)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:604)
    ... 8 more
```

My work directory:

```
.
├── javacpp-bin
├── javacpp-presets-bin
├── TestConnection.class
└── TestConnection.java
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used librealsense-platform.jar

```
$ javac -cp javacpp-presets-bin/javacpp.jar:javacpp-presets-bin/librealsense-platform.jar TestConnection.java
$ java -jar javacpp-presets-bin/javacpp.jar TestConnection
$ java -cp javacpp-presets-bin/javacpp.jar:javacpp-presets-bin/librealsense-platform.jar:. TestConnection
```